# Compiling solution checks out main project file

Tags: .net, visual-studio, tfs, vcs-checkout

I have a visual studio 2012 solution with a multiple C# library projects and a main VB.net windows forms project.

The **problem** is that, whenever I compile the solution, I get prompted to check out the main VB.net windows forms project.

But the program compiles fine even though I cancel the checkout message.
When I do check out the file before compilation and check the difference of the project file, there is no difference.

This is happening in one other project (Classic ASP.NET solution in C#.)

Has anyone had this problem and had chance to find out what is going on?

Comment: It's possible that when VS builds the solution, it edits a setting in the solution file that says what version of VS it was compiled with. Is anyone else using a different version of VS on your project? Also do a comparison with your version and most recent on the solution file and see if anything's being changed.

Comment: Yes.  Some other dev'er in my team uses VS 2010/2013.  Let me check if there is any difference.

Comment: that is probably what is causing it then. I have experienced this issue before. I'd recommend getting everyone on the same version to avoid this, although it's possible that when the version is set the the latest one, older versions won't overwrite it. I'm not sure about that though.